# getting the index of a sorted array components at the primary array using recursive function in Julia

Tags: recursion, julia

I want to get the index of sorted array components at the primary array using a recursive function.

**Important note:** I know this can be done using a half line of Julia code, But I'm trying to practice writing recursive functions!

Example:
input --> [5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4]
output (Julia) --> [3, 1, 6, 5, 4, 2]
Since the argmax of the input is 3, and after that, the next argmax is 1, and so on.

And the code which I wrote for this:

```
julia> function sort_argmax(array)
           all(==(-Inf), array) && nothing
           any(!=(-Inf), array) && vcat(argmax(array) ,sort_argmax(vcat(array[1:argmax(array)-1], -Inf,array[argmax(array)+1:end])))
       end
sort_argmax (generic function with 1 method)
```

The expected output for the given `[5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4]` Vector:

```
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 1
 6
 5
 4
 2
```

The real output:

```
julia> sort_argmax([5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4])
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 1
 6
 5
 4
 2
 0
```

There is a surplus `0` at the end of the output, and I don't expect that! How can I achieve the expected result? And, what's the reason behind emerging the last `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that there is no `nothing` as  part of the output is a clue that something may be wrong with that part of the code. When we take another look at that line:

```
           all(==(-Inf), array) && nothing
```

we see that it just *evaluates* to `nothing`, but doesn't do anything with that value. Your intention here is probably to return `nothing` from here - which needs an explicit `return` keyword unless you're at the very end of the function.

```
           all(==(-Inf), array) && return nothing
```

However, when you run that code, the output is:

```
julia> sort_argmax([5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4])
7-element Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}:
 3
 1
 6
 5
 4
 2
  nothing
```

a `Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}` is not exactly what we wanted. This happens because `nothing` is a value on its own, and takes part in the `vcat` as an argument. There are a few different ways to fix this, but the easiest/laziest way here is probably to return an empty array instead:

```
           all(==(-Inf), array) && return Int[]
```

```
julia> sort_argmax([5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4])
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 1
 6
 5
 4
 2
```

Comment: Thanks for these great explanations, Sunder! Also, adding element types as `Int64` in `empty(array, Int64)` gives the exact expected output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I just realized an `empty(array)` there doesn't make sense here - it should either be `empty(eachindex(array))` if we're being fully generic, since we want to match the type of the *indices* not the values in the array; or just an `Int[]` (empty array of `Int`egers) would do for this purpose.